# How to merge array field in document in Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have one requirement where i need to do aggregation on two records both have an array field with different value. What I need that when I do aggregation on these records the result should have one array with unique values from both different arrays. Here is example :

First record

```
 { Host:"abc.com" ArtId:"123", tags:[ "tag1", "tag2" ] }
```

Second record

```
{ Host:"abc.com" ArtId:"123", tags:[ "tag2", "tag3" ] }
```

After aggregation on host and artid i need result like this:

```
 { Host: "abc.com", ArtId: "123", count :"2", tags:[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]}
```

I tried `$addToset` in group statement but it gives me like this tags :`[["tag1","tag2"],["tag2","tag3"]]`

Could you please help me how i can achieve this in aggregation

Comment: @Neil Lunn I have moved it here. Could you please suggest me some approach which i should choose in this case if i have multiple arrays like this in document. as for each array i have to repeat the aggregation as explained by you. But if i use $addToSet in first group for each array then i will get array of array which i can parse in java to create new array for each field in that case i will run aggregation one time only for each  all records

Comment: We appear to be at a misunderstanding here. You should have run the code I presented on [dba.stackexhange.com](http://dba.stackexhange.com) where the intent was to have the question **migrated**. It does not produce an array of arrays. Will post here again as well since you have done this. You need to look at the "double" `$unwind` as well as actually run the code.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry i am not saying this code wont work it works perfectly and it solves my problem with single array but i was asking help if i have two array field or more in the document and all needs to be handled in the same way.So in that case i need to repeat the process for each array field

Comment: That is what I think you misunderstood. It wasn't about moving the question you asked yourself, it was about asking your **new** question about "multiple arrays" in the document. It's a **new** question and not an addition to the original question. You haven't asked it yet. Ask your question with all the details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### TLDR;

Modern releases should use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) with [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) after the initial [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as is shown:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "Host": "$Host", "ArtId": "$ArtId" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "tags": { "$addToSet": "$tags" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "tags": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$tags",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$setUnion": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

---

You were right in finding the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator, but when working with content in an array you generally need to process with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first. This "de-normalizes" the array entries and essentially makes a "copy" of the parent document with each array entry as a singular value in the field. That's what you need to avoid the behavior you are seeing without using that.

Your "count" poses an interesting problem though, but easily solved through the use of a "double unwind" after an initial [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Group on the compound key and get the occurrences first
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "Host": "$Host", "ArtId": "$ArtId" },
        "tcount": { "$sum": 1 },
        "ttags": { "$push": "$tags" }
    }},

    // Unwind twice because "ttags" is now an array of arrays
    { "$unwind": "$ttags" },
    { "$unwind": "$ttags" },

    // Now use $addToSet to get the distinct values        
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "tcount": { "$first": "$tcount" },
        "tags": { "$addToSet": "$ttags" }
    }},

    // Optionally $project to get the fields out of the _id key
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "Host": "$_id.Host",
        "ArtId": "$_id.ArtId",
        "count": "$tcount",
        "tags": "$ttags"
    }}
])
```

That final bit with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is also there because I used "temporary" names for each of the fields in other stages of the aggregation pipeline. This is because there is an optimization in [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) that "copies" the fields from an existing stage in the order they already appeared "before" any "new" fields are added to the document.

Otherwise the output would look like:

```js
{  "count":2 , "tags":[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ], "Host": "abc.com", "ArtId": "123" }
```

Where the fields are not in the same order as you might think. Trivial really, but it matters to some people, so worth explaining why, and how to handle.

So [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) does the work to keep the items separated and not in arrays, and doing the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) first allows you to get the "count" of the occurrences of the "grouping" key.

The [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator used later "keeps" that "count" value, as it just got "duplicated" for every value present in the "tags" array. It's all the same value anyway so it does not matter. Just pick one.